# How do I optimize a vector loss?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a loss function that returns a vector. I have another target vector, and my goal is to have the neural network return a vector that is the exact same as my target vector. In this case, I am trying to optimize each individual element of v_output - v_target. How can I do that in Pytorch?

For example, this code snippet gives me an error:

```
outputs = model(training)
loss = torch.square(outputs - labels)
loss.backward()

RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs
```

Comment: You need to reduce your loss to a scalar. Using `MSELoss` would be most appropriate here. You could also just sum or average your square errors `loss.mean().backward()`.